# Are Innate powers reused every turn or is the current manifestation just maintained

Tags: powers, anima-beyond-fantasy

In Anima: Beyond Fantasy, I am playing a mentalist and I have access to an innate slot and the energy discipline power Energy Shield. I was wondering if making that an innate power reused the power every turn recreating the shield or just maintained the current one.

The passage about innate powers says this:

> Once they successfully activate the power they must declare that they want to keep it as an innate power. Then starting on the next turn they need not roll any dice to use it.

This leads me to believe that this means that it is reused every turn which in my case is reusing the shield. I may be wrong.

Comment: if someone better at phrasing might edit this for the sake of sanity if might help. Im not sure how clear I made this.

Comment: Seems clear enough to me! I don't play Anima: Beyond Fantasy, but there's an outsider's perspective (so you're doing at least something right phrasing things).

Comment: I wrote it when I was still groggy. so I wasnt sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an innate slot for a power maintains the power without rolling. It is not recreated every turn: namely, if an attack eliminated all the life points of your Energy Shield, you would need to manifest it again, rather than it reappearing for free at the beginning of your next turn.

Comment: Additionally, I remember that maintaining shields has a specific rule that states that the shield loses 5 (or maybe 10) life points per turn. So you cannot maintain a shield at the start of the day and have it ready for an eventual combat.  Remember also that you maintain your powers even if you are sleeping or unconscious.

Comment: @Random I suspect that that rule doesn't apply to all shields; In fact, there's at least one shield in the Path of Creation that has a daily maintenance cost and regenerates lost life points. That said, maintaining a shield at all times is still a bad idea. For one thing, shields are explicitly visible to ordinary vision, and therefore very likely to attract the attention of the various witch-hunting organisations in the setting.

Comment: @GMJoe, you are right, of course, but perfect shield as essence shield (from the essence path) are exceptions, and psychic powers don't have any of these rules (I haven't checked Arcana Exxet, so maybe electromagnetic shield has it). Some 'magic' shields are invisible (telekinetic shield), and I think (but this could be house-rued by our GM) that some only appear when hit, like the proper energy shield. I was just pointing out an important rule when maintaining shields that happens to also be applied to magic and ki shields.